# How do I cure the cause of Hibernate exception "IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter"?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, exception, orm

How do I cure the cause of the occasional exception `IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter` that Hibernate throws when my program attempts to load a user by name from the database?

Am I incorrectly mapping column `USER_RV` in table `User` to class `Integer` instead of `BigDecimal` or some other integer type?  Note that the same application maps `NUMBER` columns in other tables to `Integer` objects, but Hibernate **does not** throw this exception when populating an object with a row from those tables.

Further note that the program enables **RMI cache replication** for the **User cache only**.  Might this exception be related to cache replication?  Is it a bug in Ehcache or Hibernate?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.db.spgit.abstrack.model.User.rv; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.db.spgit.abstrack.model.User.rv
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:676)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1048)
    at com.db.abstrack.dao.hibernate.AbstrackDaoHibernate.findByCriteria(AbstrackDaoHibernate.java:57)
    at com.db.abstrack.dao.hibernate.UserDaoHibernate.loadByName(UserDaoHibernate.java:63)
    at com.db.spgit.abstrack.manager.QuoteManager.populateUser(QuoteManager.java:330)
    at com.db.spgit.abstrack.manager.QuoteManager.populateOwnerUK(QuoteManager.java:307)
    at com.db.spgit.abstrack.manager.QuoteManager.populateGuids(QuoteManager.java:254)
    at com.db.spgit.abstrack.manager.QuoteManager.addQuoteReturnVwRfqUK(QuoteManager.java:429)
    at com.db.spgit.abstrack.manager.QuoteManager$$FastClassByCGLIB$$d817accb.invoke(&lt;generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:700)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:635)
    at com.db.spgit.abstrack.manager.QuoteManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$cc8d0025.addQuoteReturnVwRfqUK(&lt;generated>)
    at com.db.abstrack.ejb.RfqBean.addRfqDraftListUK(RfqBean.java:370)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.db.spgit.abstrack.model.User.rv
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3514)
    at org.hibernate.cache.entry.CacheEntry.assemble(CacheEntry.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.cache.entry.CacheEntry.assemble(CacheEntry.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.assembleCacheEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:846)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:557)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.assemble(ManyToOneType.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.get(StandardQueryCache.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultFromQueryCache(Loader.java:2152)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2117)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2087)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$36.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@6be0d6
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:42)
    ... 101 more
```

Definition of class `User`:

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Table(name="TB_USER"
    ,schema="ABSOL_USER"
)
public class User  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private String id;
     private String userName;
     private Integer rv;

     public User() {
     }

     public User(String userName, Integer rv) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.rv = rv;
     }

     @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="guid")@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")

     @Column(name="USER_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
     public String getId() {
         return this.id;
     }

     public void setId(String id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     @Column(name="USER_NAME", nullable=false, length=20)
     public String getUserName() {
         return this.userName;
     }

     public void setUserName(String userName) {
         this.userName = userName;
     }

     @Column(name="USER_RV", precision=22, scale=0)
     public Integer getRv() {
         return this.rv;
     }

     public void setRv(Integer rv) {
         this.rv = rv;
     }
}
```

Definition of table `TB_USER`:

```
CREATE TABLE "ABSOL_OWNER"."TB_USER" (
   "USER_ID" RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID(), 
   "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   "USER_RV" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
   PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ID")
)
```

Environment:

- Hibernate 3.3.2.GA
- Ehcache 2.2.0
- WebLogic Server 10.3.2
- Oracle database
- Caching User objects
- Enabled RMI cache replication via remote key invalidation

Comment: After disabling RMI cache replication, the program no longer throws this exception, so it appears that there is some issue with Ehcache or Hibernate.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my answer, as Pascal answered it the same way, and you seem to have found a different problem.  I have never used the RMI cache replication, so I don't have a lot of help for you there.  I would guess it is likely a problem in the RMI replication code, rather than EHCache directly.

Comment: aperkins, thank you for your answer attempt.  Will let you know the solution should I hear back from Terracotta or the Hibernate community.

Comment: I've posted this question to the Hibernate User forums at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1006842&start=0 and the Ehcache User mailing list at http://lists.terracotta.org/pipermail/ehcache-list/2010-September/000263.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this exception is due to a bug in Hibernate.  One of my teammates found a related bug report, *[Re-assembling entity from clustered JBoss Cache may fail with "argument type mismatch"](http://spiritandopportunity.com/list/6/89180.html)*, that occurs when using Hibernate and [JBoss Cache](http://jboss.org/jbosscache/).

According to the report, setting Hibernate property `hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries` to *true* avoids the exception.  According to the Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html), this property "forces Hibernate to store data in the second-level cache in a more human-friendly format".  Apparently, structured cache entries also ensure that Hibernate correctly maps properties of an object in the second-level cache to the corresponding property in an entity.

[Javalobby](http://java.dzone.com/) has an interesting [article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html) that explains how Hibernate uses the second-level cache.

Do versions of Hibernate after 3.3.2GA also exhibit this behaviour?

Comment: I am having the same problem and have tried to enable the 'hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries' to true, but its does not help and I am using hibernate 3.6.5.Final, any idea on how I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that a `NUMBER` column type can be cast into an `Integer`. Try a `NUMBER(10,0)` instead.

Comment: Changing the precision of the number does not eliminate this problem, so I think it may be a problem with Ehcache or Hibernate.  I will try Hibernate 3.4.0.GA.

Comment: @Derek AFAIK, this is the column type that Hibernate would generate with the Oracle dialect for an integer. You can check the dialect.

Comment: Pascal, I have `NUMBER` columns in other tables that map to `Integer`, but Hibernate does not throw this exception for those mappings.  Unlike for `User`, the caches for these other entities do not have RMI replication enabled.  When I disable RMI replication for the `User` cache, Hibernate no longer throws this exception.  So, this exception may be a symptom of an underlying replication problem masquerading as a type mapping problem.

Comment: @Derek It would be interesting to see what is in the cache before re hydratation. But it looks like a bug.

Comment: Pascal, can I use ehcache-server or some other tool to provide you with a snapshot of the cache before this exception happens?

Comment: @Derek I'm not working for Terracotta. You'll get more chances to get the problem fixed if you raise an issue in their bug tracker and provide required information :)

Comment: Pascal, I posted a message on the Ehcache forums and searched their bug list, but did not find a bug reporting a similar exception.  I'll see what kind of responses I get.

Comment: @Derek It might be an "unknown" problem.