# Spring: hibernate + ehcache

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, caching, ehcache

I'm working with a spring project using hibernate and look to implement second-level cache using ehcache. I see a number of approaches to this:

1. [`spring-modules-cache`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/ehcache/package-frame.html) which introduces the `@Cacheable` annotation
2. [`ehcache-spring-annotations`](https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) a toolset which aims to be the successor of `spring-modules-cache`.
3. [`Hibernate cache`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache) is nicely integrated into hibernate itself to perform caching using e.g., the `@Cache` annotation.
4. [`Programmatic cache`](http://ehcache.org/documentation/samples.html#Using_Caches) using proxies. Annotation based config quickly becomes either limited or complex (e.g., several levels of annotation nesting)

Personally I don't think `spring-modules-cache` is thorough enough, hence I would probably prefer consider the more actively developed `ehcache-spring-annotations`. `Hibernate cache` though seems to be most complete implementation (e.g., both read and write cache etc).

What would motivate which toolset to use? Please share your caching experience ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Our project uses option 3.  We apply annotation `org.hibernate.annotations.Cache` to entities that we cache in an [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/), configure Ehcache using `ehcache.xml`, and enable and configure the [Hibernate second-level cache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html) in `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
    <!-- Enable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
        net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
        net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</property>     
    <property name="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

For most entities, we use cache concurrency strategy [`CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cache/CacheConcurrencyStrategy.html):

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
```

Our Maven project uses Hibernate 3.3.2GA and Ehcache 2.2.0:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Cool, how's that working out for you, satisfactory? After trying options 1 & 2 I feel they are still quite limited and not at all so concise as I would wish.

Comment: Our experience configuring Hibernate and Ehcache was relatively pain free until we enabled synchronous RMI cache replication in our cluster.  When enabled, Hibernate started throwing weird exceptions.  To resolve these exceptions, we enabled `hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries`.  Later versions of Hibernate may not have this problem, but when we were trying to solve this issue, our environment wasn't compatible with Hibernate 3.5.6.

Comment: I documented this experience at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631349/how-do-i-cure-the-cause-of-hibernate-exception-illegalargumentexception-occurred.

Comment: We have since moved the Hibernate configuration from `hibernate.cfg.xml` to the Spring application context.  Read details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379791/how-do-you-translate-hibernate-class-mappings-to-a-spring-application-context/5407890#5407890.

Answer (score 3):

Spring 3.1 has a new built-in cache abstraction. [Read here](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/23/spring-3-1-m1-caching/).