# How do you translate Hibernate class mappings to a Spring application context?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, configuration

How do you configure the [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) class mappings of class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) in the [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) [application context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html)?  I want to move the [session factory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) class mappings from the following [`hibernate.cfg.xml`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig) to the corresponding Spring session factory bean so that I may eliminate `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

File `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- ... -->
        <mapping resource="Queries.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping class="com.company.app.common.model.Account" />
        <mapping class="com.company.app.common.model.AccountCategory" />
        <mapping class="com.company.app.common.model.AssetType" />
        <mapping class="com.company.app.common.model.Book" />
        <mapping class="com.company.app.model.AssetTypeCategory" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

File `spring-application-context.xml`:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>

    <!-- Instead of the above, I want to use the following. Where and
    how do I define the class mappings so that I may eliminate
    hibernate.cfg.xml? -->
    <--
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>Queries.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    -->
</bean>
```

Comment: I want to eliminate the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file by moving its contents into the Spring application context.

Comment: Are these annotated entity classes?

Comment: Yes, these are annotated classes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're using JPA-annotated classes, you can use `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` instead of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, and inject the classes directly into the Spring bean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
       <list>
           <value>com.company.app.common.model.Account</value>
           <value>com.company.app.common.model.AccountCategory</value>
           <value>com.company.app.common.model.AssetType</value>
           <value>com.company.app.common.model.Book</value>
           <value>com.company.app.model.AssetTypeCategory</value>      
       </list>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
       <list>
          <value>Queries.hbm.xml</value>
       </list>
    </property>        
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Where do I place `Queries.hbm.xml` which contains some HQL queries?

Comment: @Derek: `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` extends `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, so you can still use all the same properties as before, including `mappingResources`.

Answer (score 9):

As a slight variation on skaffman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379791/how-do-you-translate-hibernate-class-mappings-to-a-spring-application-context/5379927#5379927), I used property [`packagesToScan`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) of class [`AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html) to avoid listing all of the individual model class names:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
       <list>
           <value>com.company.app.common.model</value>
       </list>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
       <list>
          <value>Queries.hbm.xml</value>
       </list>
    </property>        
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I learned about this property from the excellent book [*Spring in Action, Third Edition*](http://manning.com/walls4/).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, and this worked for me -

```
<bean id="auditCoreSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="auditCoreDataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.odeon.audit.dao.entity" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.odeon.audit.dao.entity.AuditLogEntity</value>
            <value>com.odeon.audit.dao.entity.AuditLogApplicationEtity</value>
            <value>com.odeon.audit.dao.entity.AuditLogModuleEntity</value>
            <value>com.odeon.audit.dao.entity.AuditLogOperationEntity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">#{auditCoreProp.getString('jdbc.dialect')}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">#{auditCoreProp.getString('jdbc.show_sql')}</prop>
            <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">#{auditCoreProp.getString('jdbc.hbm2ddl.auto')}
            </prop>
            <!-- prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```