# hibernate configuration with mapping classes in spring config

Tags: spring, hibernate

well i need almost the same thing as in this question [How do you translate Hibernate class mappings to a Spring application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379791/how-do-you-translate-hibernate-class-mappings-to-a-spring-application-context?rq=1)

but i shouldn't use annotations, i need to save xml mapping, so how should i specify mappings in spring config?

P. S. sorry for possible duplicate, but i have seen only annotation-based suggestions

my current configuration with annotations : 
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/XE</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.foo.domain.News"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

applicationContext.xml sessionFactory bean:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${DIALECT}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `mappingLocations` property on your `LocalSessionFactoryBean`:

```
<property name="mappingLocations">
    <list>
        <value>classpath:/path/to/mapping.hbm.xml</value>
        ...
    </list>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

The hibernate documentation is quite good.

Here you have some simple examples to start with:
[Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-associations)

You have to create you mapping xml like:

```
Person.hbm.xml  (which maps Person.java)
```

```
<class name="Person" table="PERSON">
    <id name="id" column="PERSON_ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="age"/>
    <property name="firstname"/>
    <property name="lastname"/>
</class>
```

Then add this file to your hibernate configuration

```
<mapping resource="Person.hbm.xml"/>
```