# Caching in Spring Web service?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I need to load some data from DB to Cache on server start up.And once a request came, need to take the data from this cache.Also need to refresh cache in frequent intervals.It would be help if somebody provide way for achieving this.I am using Spring 3.1.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of cache implementations available:

- The [Spring Cache](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) abstraction
- [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) (which is one possible provider for Spring Cache)
- [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`LoadingCache`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html)
- Infinispan as user1516873 suggests
- A plain [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) from the JDK if you don't want more dependencies
- etc.

Comment: Thanks For the answer.Seems Ehcache is better option.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

[Spring: hibernate + ehcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270998/spring-hibernate-ehcache)

As you will see my recommendation is to use hibernate second level cache and your problem will be fixed at configuration level.

Comment: thanks for the answer.I am not using hibernate.Without using Hibernate how will this achieve?

Comment: What are you using for persistence?

Comment: You still can use ehcache due to spring have big and transparent support for it. Check out this resources: http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/jdbc, http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/spring, http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/23/spring-3-1-m1-caching/. I think you should bed for it since is known that ehcache is the preferred way to do caching in spring.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Infinispan](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Getting+Started+Guide).

It modern, open source and easy to use cache. You can embed it and use directly, or use it as second level cache in hibernate.