# No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defiend, bean reference issue

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I am using `spring-framework 4.0.2.RELEASE` and `hibernate-3.6.4.Final`.

This spring data `jpa` configuration gives me an error:

```
No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' is defiend.
```

However I found that if I change bean name `emf` to `entityManagerFactory` then, there is no problem.

Can somebody explain why the bean reference does not work here?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- http://drypot.com/post/95?p=6 spring + hibernate: with JPA -->

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="emf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        p:packagesToScan="${entitymanager.packagesToScan}" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <!--prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop-->

                <!-- hibernate ehcache
                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270998/spring-hibernate-ehcache
                 --> 
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">${hibernate.cache.provider_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.factory_class}</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Spring Data JPA by default looks for a bean named `entityManagerFactory`. If you have another bean name tell this to Spring Data JPA (or simply rename your bean).

Comment: @M.Deinum, I think I tell that like this `<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />` however it does not work.

Comment: There is somewhere a bean, configuration part etc. that requires that bean, without the full configuration or at least the actual stacktrace (instead of only the message) that is hard to determine. When using Spring Data Jpa you need to put the reference to `emf` into the `<jpa:repositories />` element (or `EnableJpaRepository` annotation those by default expect a bean named `entityManagerFactory`).

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks I got a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with Spring Data JPA it, by default, looks for a bean named `entityManagerFactory`. This is the default for both the xml namespace based configuration (`<jpa:repositories />`) and for the java bases configuration (`@EnableJpaRepositories`).

If you have a bean with another name you will have to make that clear to Spring Data JPA so that it can select the proper `EntityManagerFactory` to use.

```
<task:repositories entity-manager-factory-ref="emf" />
```

or java config

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef="emf")
```

Links

1. Spring Data JPA [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.namespace)
2. @EnableJpaRepositories [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html)

Comment: Thank you. this is the answer! https://github.com/sh1nj1/spring-data-jpa-template/commit/81c41c31fa59c9f0d7f494fc1b3661737b31f39b

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting your EntityManagerFactory specifing your bean's name like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "emf")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't use `EntityManagerFactory` directly in the code. I just use Spring-Data-JPA's `Repository`.

Comment: For injecting the `EntityManagerFactory` it is recommended to use `@PersistenceContext` instead of `@Autowired`.