# Hibernate One-to-Many relationship data insertion error

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am having Project Class POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project", catalog = "primavera")
public class Project implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer projectId;
    private Date endDate;
    private String projectDesc;
    private String projectName;
    private String projectTitle;
    private Date startDate;
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>(0);

    public Project() {
    }

    public Project(Date endDate, String projectDesc, String projectName,
            String projectTitle, Date startDate, Set<Task> tasks) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.projectDesc = projectDesc;
        this.projectName = projectName;
        this.projectTitle = projectTitle;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "project_id")
    public Integer getProjectId() {
        return this.projectId;
    }

    public void setProjectId(Integer projectId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "endDate", length = 19)
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return this.endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "projectDesc")
    public String getProjectDesc() {
        return this.projectDesc;
    }

    public void setProjectDesc(String projectDesc) {
        this.projectDesc = projectDesc;
    }

    @Column(name = "projectName")
    public String getProjectName() {
        return this.projectName;
    }

    public void setProjectName(String projectName) {
        this.projectName = projectName;
    }

    @Column(name = "projectTitle")
    public String getProjectTitle() {
        return this.projectTitle;
    }

    public void setProjectTitle(String projectTitle) {
        this.projectTitle = projectTitle;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "startDate", length = 19)
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return this.startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_task", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "project_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "task_id") })
    public Set<Task> getTasks() {
        return this.tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(Set<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

}
```

having relation with Task Class POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task", catalog = "primavera")
public class Task implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer taskId;
    private Integer depth;
    private Double duration;
    private String durationUnit;
    private Date endDate;
    private Integer parentId;
    private Integer percentDone;
    private Integer priority;
    private Date startDate;
    private Integer taskIndex;
    private String taskName;

    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(Integer depth, Double duration, String durationUnit,
            Date endDate, Integer parentId, Integer percentDone,
            Integer priority, Date startDate, Integer taskIndex,
            String taskName) {
        this.depth = depth;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.durationUnit = durationUnit;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.percentDone = percentDone;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.taskIndex = taskIndex;
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public Task(String string, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "task_id")
    public Integer getTaskId() {
        return this.taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(Integer taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    @Column(name = "depth")
    public Integer getDepth() {
        return this.depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(Integer depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    @Column(name = "duration", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public Double getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Double duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Column(name = "durationUnit")
    public String getDurationUnit() {
        return this.durationUnit;
    }

    public void setDurationUnit(String durationUnit) {
        this.durationUnit = durationUnit;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "endDate", length = 19)
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return this.endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "parentId")
    public Integer getParentId() {
        return this.parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    @Column(name = "percentDone")
    public Integer getPercentDone() {
        return this.percentDone;
    }

    public void setPercentDone(Integer percentDone) {
        this.percentDone = percentDone;
    }

    @Column(name = "priority")
    public Integer getPriority() {
        return this.priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(Integer priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "startDate", length = 19)
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return this.startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "taskIndex")
    public Integer getTaskIndex() {
        return this.taskIndex;
    }

    public void setTaskIndex(Integer taskIndex) {
        this.taskIndex = taskIndex;
    }

    @Column(name = "taskName")
    public String getTaskName() {
        return this.taskName;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

}
```

I am trying to assign data to my POJO by below code using Json

```
Set<Task> taskdata = new HashSet<Task>();
        taskdata.add(new Task(null,null,null,endD1,null,null,null,startD1,null,null));

jsonObject.put("projectTitle", jsonObject.getString("title"));
        jsonObject.put("projectName", jsonObject.getString("name"));
        jsonObject.put("projectDesc", jsonObject.getString("description").replace("\u200b", ""));
        jsonObject.put("startDate", startD);
        jsonObject.put("endDate", endD);
        jsonObject.put("tasks", taskdata);

Project project = (Project) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject, Project.class);
```

but it didn't seems **to be work even though i am passing the Set as taskdata** and also I am getting error like

**35802 [http-8085-4] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: com.kintu.projectmgt.model.Task, getter method of property: taskId**

Please help me to find the problem which prevents my data to be inserted completely to database.

Comment: check this answer, might be a hibernate bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631349/how-do-i-cure-the-cause-of-hibernate-exception-illegalargumentexception-occurre. Try setting `hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true`

Comment: not a solution still same error. But one more thing is this the right way i am assigning data to my Project class having relation with Task class, using JSON ?? or do I have to use some other technique to get data inserted completely having one-to-many relationship between them.

Comment: It should be alright, but you can easily debug this and check if all necessary fields have been set in the `Project` instance created by `JSONObject.toBean()`

Comment: when i create the instance of Project i get all the values which i am assigning to task. Means its perfect now when the hibernate executes the query for Project insertion as `insert 
        into
            primavera.project
            (endDate, projectDesc, projectName, projectTitle, startDate) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` and after that error again **33752 [http-8085-3] ERROR org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: com.kintu.projectmgt.model.Task, getter method of property: taskId**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a strategy like

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

or

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
```

Normally `@GeneratedValue` in default mode is used to write into Long.
And also `OneToMany` might expect a `ManyToOne` in the other model class.

Comment: nope not a solution still error comes there. Actually I think the way I am assigning values from JsonObject to Project is not the correct. Do you have any solution for this